# Nested case select logic in SQL

Tags: sql, select, nested, case

[image]

I want to create the Platform column. Calculation column is a middle step. I will use Drive as an example.First, Product Level 1 (PL1) and Product Level 2(PL2) columns decide what's in Calculation column.So if PL2=FIN4178 and  Quantity>0, this party will be labeled as Drive first in the calculation column. If PL1=FIN595 and Quantity>0, it will be labeled as Dash in calculation column. but if the same party 1234 has both Dash and Drive, it will be then labeled as Drive in Platform column. So there is an order, Drive then websuite then Dash then Candian web then Lightspeed then PFW. All other parties will be "Other Baseline".

I'm very new to SQL and couldn't figure it out. I think it is a nested case select logic. Can anyone help? Only the Select statement is enough, thanks in advance!

If any other information you need me to share, please feel free to ask.

Comment: So does Party decide Platform?  Also do you have your calculation column already outputting that or is that part of the question?

Comment: I don't have Calculation column already. The product level 1 and product level 2 columns decide what's in calculation column first, then calculation and party ID together decide Platform. Basically, same party ID can map to multiple results in calculation ,but at the end, i want to group them to Platform. Hope i made myself clear. Thanks Aaron!

Comment: Can you store this logic in a table in your database?  Then you just have to JOIN it to calculate the Platform.

Comment: @BaconBits Unfortunately i can't store this in the database, at least not now. I'm trying to pull some raw data for an one-time analysis, so if i can sql it out this time, that would be enough for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can add another column called 'calculation priority' and set a priority number for each of your calculations. For example you want 'Drive' or 'FIN4178' to have a priority of 1 and then list the rest of the calculation priorities.

```
         calcPriority = CASE WHEN productlevel1 = 'FIN595' or productlevel2 = 'FIN595' then 3
                             WHEN productlevel1 = 'FIN4178' or productlevel2 = 'FIN4178' then 1
                             WHEN productlevel1 = 'FIN4179' or productlevel2 = 'FIN4179' then 2
                             WHEN productlevel1 = 'FIN5599' or productlevel2 = 'FIN5599' then 5
                             WHEN productlevel1 = 'FIN1385' or productlevel2 = 'FIN1385' then 6
                             WHEN productlevel1 = 'FIN5596' or productlevel2 = 'FIN5596' then 4
                        END
```

Then you can break up the data into groups grouped by your 'PARTY' column and select caculation = min(calculationPriority) so each group only contains the highest priority item per row.

Finally you build your platform column with a simple case statement as follows

```
    case when maxOfParty = 6 then 'PFW'
                        when maxOfparty = 5 then 'Lightspeed'
                        when maxOfParty = 4 then 'Canadian web'
                        when maxOfParty = 3 then 'Dash'
                        when maxOfParty = 2 then 'webSuite'
                        when maxOfParty = 1 then 'Drive'
```